# Terraform Version 1.1.9 upgrade

Tags: terraform

currently we are using tf bundle to upgrade terraform version and have it used in a form of docker image for every build but now got to know that Hashhicorp have stopped support for tf bundle since 0.15 for long term so i just need to know how can i lock my providers for new version 1.1.9 ? or
how to create docker image with terraform 1.1.9 binary installed ?

Answer (score 0):

There are various options for forcing Terraform to use a particular set of providers, depending on what your reason is for doing so.

---

If your primary goal is only to ensure that you keep using exactly the same provider versions until you explicitly upgrade, modern Terraform actually has that behavior built in: check your `.terraform.lock.hcl` file into version control after `terraform init` succeeds and then Terraform will guarantee to select the same versions of those providers or fail if it cannot achieve that. You can then use `terraform init -upgrade` explicitly if you want Terraform to ignore the lock file and look upstream for new versions instead.

---

If instead your goal is to avoid reaching out over the network to obtain these providers, you can place the providers you intend to use in one of the [implied local mirror directories](https://www.terraform.io/cli/config/config-file#implied-local-mirror-directories), which Terraform will scan on startup and thus force use of local installation only for those particular providers.

If you are building a Docker image as you mentioned in your question, the image will presumably host the Linux version of Terraform and therefore you could arrange for the providers you need to be installed in `/usr/share/terraform/plugins` inside the Docker image, in which case Terraform should find them in there and install them from that directory instead.

---

The "implied local mirror directory" mechanism is a default behavior Terraform offers with no explicit configuration aside from placing the providers in one of the prescribed locations, but you can get more control over it by [explicitly configuring the provider installation strategy](https://www.terraform.io/cli/config/config-file#explicit-installation-method-configuration).

One advantage of explicit configuration is that you can tell Terraform to never attempt installation from anywhere except the local directory, which is a more restrictive configuration than what Terraform will create for itself by default because normally it will only disable remote installation for providers it already sees inside one of the local mirror directories, and so it will still try to install any other providers over the network.

In the home directory of the user that will be running Terraform (inside the Docker image, if you are using one), create a file `.terraformrc` with the following content:

```
provider_installation {
  filesystem_mirror {
    path = "/usr/share/terraform/plugins"
  }
}
```

Because this `provider_installation` block *only* has a `filesystem_mirror` block -- and in particular, it has no `direct {}` block -- this tells Terraform that its only available installation method is to install from the given local directory.

Unlike the implied mirror strategy above then, this will make `terraform init` fail altogether if someone tries to initialize a configuration that includes a provider that isn't in the local directory, rather than attempting to install it from its origin registry.